# How to Delete Link from SharePoint to OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint

My university has a SharePoint repository (on sharepoint.com) that I use at most a time or two per year.  The relevant page has an "Add shortcut to OneDrive" button.  I naïvely clicked it, expecting a folder to appear in OneDrive so I wouldn't have to search for the link any more.

It added a folder, all right, then downloaded the entire 9 GB of the SharePoint repository.  The really bad news is that deleting a file from the OneDrive folder *also deletes it* from the SharePoint repository.  (Restoring from by recycle folder also restores to SharePoint, so I haven't broken anything yet.)

How can I delete this link?  (If I need administrative help, what do I ask the administrator to do?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into OneDrive on the web and look for a folder with the shortcut icon. Click the ellipses next to the folder name and select "Remove" as shown in the fist image. Alternatively you can right click the folder in File Explorer and select "Remove shortcut" from the OneDrive context menu.

[image]

Additionally, you can select the Sync button in the Sharepoint document library to sync the folder to your OneDrive client. If you have Files on Demand enabled in your OneDrive client then files will only be downloaded from the Sharepoint document library as you access them.

[image]

[image]